# Ubuntu Chrome - Reset Font Settings

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I was playing around with the font settings of my chrome on ubuntu 18.04. Now they are messed up and I can't find my screenshot of the initial settings. Can some one of you share their default font settings of chrome.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

So I could solve the issue without knowing the default values like so.

`bash
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable # uninstall chrome
sudo rm -r .config/google-chrome`

And reinstalled the `.deb` package form google. Now everything looks good

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Appearance:

[image]

Customize Fonts:

[image]

Comment: Are these the defaults? I thought it would be some dejavu font ^^

Comment: Yes, I install chrome and do not change anything special to answer you in this ticket. Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Downloaded and installed from https://www.google.com/chrome/ as deb package.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I can't find Times New Roman in the dropdown. Had to go another way :/

Comment: This answer deserves to get green tick, I had lost my color emojis but when I did this it worked like a charm !!! AWESOME !!! Thanks a looooooot !!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the original fonts, here's how to do it:

First, close Google Chrome, so your changes don't get overwritten.

Go to your Google Chrome settings folder, in Ubuntu, i found it in `.config/google-chrome`

In this folder, open up the file `Default/Preferences`,

Search and replace references to your fonts in the file with the string "Custom". In my case they were all at the end of the file, so it was easy to replace.

After this, open up Google Chrome again, and your fonts will be reset.

Comment: `jq '.webkit.webprefs.fonts' ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`
can see those settings

Answer (score 0):

The same font rendering issue in Ubuntu 22.04 solved only with

```
sudo rm -r .config/google-chrome
```